# Bash if/else exist status when running commands

Tags: bash

New to bash programming. Looking to program if/else by capturing the exit status of a command and printing a response to the screen.

For example, one of the commands may be to create a swap file.

```
printf ("Creating swap file...", %)
fallocate -l 4G swapfile

if [ $? ]
  echo "ok"
else
  echo "failed"
fi
```

The output to screen should look like:

```
Creating swap file...                 ok
```

Questions:

Is printf the proper command and if so, what do I use for the %?

How do I compare the exist status's for pass/fail?

If more than one command is used, will it just use the last exist status or will it take the fail of any of them to report 'failed'?

Comment: `echo -n 'Creating swap file... '` . The -n will omit the newline. Then just use the regular echo under your conditional compounds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if` statement's very purpose is to examine a command's exit code.

```
if fallocate -l 4G swapfile; then
    echo "Success."
else
    echo "Failure."
fi
```

If you put a compound command or pipeline, the last command's status is the result. This is how the shell works, and is in no way specific to `if`.

```
if false; true; then
    echo "Always true"
fi
```

The command `[` examines its argument; it will return true if it is non-empty, as it always will be when the value you examine is `$?`. You could say `[ $? -eq 0 ]` but this is obviously just a needless complication. In fact, directly examining `$?` is almost never necessary; it's a common antipattern (though you see it a lot, because most shell scripts are written by beginners who never learned the language properly).

The `printf` command is generally to be preferred over `echo`, but your syntax is incorrect. Try

```
printf "Creating swap file...\n"
```

Omit the `\n` if you don't want a newline.

Comment: See also [Why is testing "$?" to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
printf "Creating swap file..."
if fallocate -l 4G swapfile; then
  echo "   ok"
else
  echo "   failed"
fi
```

The "condition" after `if` is an arbitrary command. If it succeeds (exit status `0`), the `then` block is executed, otherwise the `else` block. The easiest way to satisfy your requirements is to just put your command(s) inside the `if`.

Answer (score 1):

This is your code:

```
printf ("Creating swap file...", %)
fallocate -l 4G swapfile

if [ $? ]
  echo "ok"
else
  echo "failed"
fi
```

You are using `printf` oddly. It's an ordinary shell command, so no parentheses are needed. Also, that trailing `%` look out of place. In this case, and at that point in the code, you have nothing more to output other than a static string, so no format specifier is needed. So, **yes**, `printf` is the proper command to use here, because it doesn't output a newline at the end of its output unless you tell it to.

If you'd just want to act on the exit status of `fallocate`, then you may put the command in the `if`-statement directly, like this:

```
printf "Creating swap file...\t"

if fallocate -l 4G swapfile; then
  echo "ok"
else
  echo "failed"
fi
```

If you have a pipeline, the exit status of the pipeline will be that of the *last* command in the pipeline:

```
if cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3; then
# ...
fi
```

This is also true for compound commands like `cmd;cmd`, `{cmd;cmd}`, `(cmd;cmd)` etc.

To have pipelines return the exit status of the *last command in a pipeline **that fails*** in `bash`, you will need to set the `pipefail` option:

```
set -o pipefail
```

To get at the exit statuses of the intermediate pipeline commands in `bash` you may inspect the `PIPESTATUS` array after executing the pipeline:

```
$ false | true | true | false
$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
1 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an expression http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html in the if statement:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ...
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "ok"
else
        echo "failed"
fi
exit 0
```

Best,
  Julian

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need. It will omit the newline after printing `Creating....`. Then it will check the output and print "ok" or "error" on the same line.

```
echo -n "Creating swap file ... "
fallocate -l 4G swapfile
local status=$?
if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "error"
else
    echo "ok"
fi
return $status
```